# Python multiprocessing function parameter not copied

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing, copy

Parameter seems to not be copied just after process execution

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def f(o):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"step 4 {o} should be 0!!!!!!!!!")
    o['a'] = 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"step 5 {o}")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=1)

    t = {'a': 0}
    print(f"step 1 {t}")
    pool.apply_async(f, (t,))
    t['a'] = 3
    print(f"step 2 {t}")
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f"step 3 {t}")
```

result is:

```
step 1 {'a': 0}
step 2 {'a': 3}
step 4 {'a': 3} should be 0!!!!!!!!!
step 5 {'a': 1}
step 3 {'a': 3}
```

And if we add a small sleep just after apply_async it works:

```
    pool.apply_async(f, (t,))
    time.sleep(0.0001) #!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is the dict copied or not????

Comment: Looks like `apply_async()` doesn't wait for the child process to be forked. It returns immediately, and then `t['a'] = 3` happens before the child process is created. When the child is created, it gets a copy of the modified dictionary.

Comment: This is a race condition between the main thread and the thread that feeds tasks to the pool of workers (not specifically a race with fork here actually, so this could actually happen on any OS). By using a mutable variable (dictionaries are mutable), the value is changed before the `pool._task_handler` thread can package up the arguments and send them to a child process for execution.

Comment: not that it is the same behavior with  concurrent.futures.
forcing the copy with pool.apply_async(f, (t.copy(),)) fix it.